# Função Filter retorna undefined - Jquery

Tags: jquery

Olá!

Alguem pode me dizer o que está errado ?

Usando a função filter, estou vendo um retorno undefined.

**Javascript**

```js
var enum_toastr_type = {
    success: 1,
    info: 2,
    warning: 3,
    error: 4
}

/***# PAGELOAD START #***/
$(document).ready(function() {
    toastr.options = {
        progressBar: true,
        closeButton: false,
        positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
        timeOut: '20000'
    }
    /*
 var visited = localStorage.getItem('visited');
    if(!visited) {
    setTimeout('get_mensagem_ajax()', 50);
  localStorage.setItem('visited', true);
    }
 */
    setTimeout('get_mensagem_ajax()', 50);
});
/***# PAGELOAD END #***/


/*** Métodos Início ***/
function exibe_mensagem(mensagens) {
    var msg = mensagens.filter(function(x) {
        return x;
    });
    exibe_mensagem_toastr(msg);
}

function exibe_mensagem_toastr(mensagens) {
    $(mensagens).each(function() {
        //console.log(this.mensagem);
        switch (this.tipo_notificacao) {
            case enum_toastr_type.info:
                toastr.info(this.mensagem);
                break;
            case enum_toastr_type.success:
                toastr.success(this.mensagem);
                break;
            case enum_toastr_type.warning:
                toastr.warning(this.mensagem);
                break;
            case enum_toastr_type.error:
                toastr.error(this.mensagem);
                break;
        }
    });
}
/*** Métodos Fim ***/

/***# AJAX START #***/
function get_mensagem_ajax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: 'notificacao/get_mensagem',
        success: (function(data) {
            exibe_mensagem(data);
        }),
        error: (function(erro) {
            trata_erro_ajax(erro);
        })
    });
}
/*** AJAX END ***/
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tenta assim $(mensagens).filter

Comment: Não deu certo tambem

Comment: voce viu se o $(mensagens) ou mensagens está retornando algo? pode ser que ele ja nao esteja sendo encontrado.
se puder, poste seu html tambem

Comment: Ambos estão retornando e exibindo o array, conforme imagem, mas quando vou verificar o `this`, na função `exibe_mensagem_toastr` tenho undefined.

Comment: entendi, entao vamos outra tentativa: 
$(mensagens).each(function(i, item) {....
e ai tenta acessar: item.tipo_notificacao

Comment: Tente adicionando o índice `[1]` na variável: `$(mensagens[1]).each(function() {`

Comment: Sim, com o índice eu consigo, mas descobri o problema,o problema está no enum, que esperava o tipo_notificacao como `INT`, mas estava vindo com `string`, corrigi o retorno no servidor e funcionou sem problemas.
Muito obrigado a voces